# Checkbox value not working within a function

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="ferrari" id="F40" onclick="addToBasket(this);">F40

function addToBasket() {
    var bkval = $(this).val();
    console.log(bkval);
}
```

Why is jQuery not getting the value of the checkbox? I can't seem to understand why, it gets the value fine if I use a standard onClick but it doesn't seem to like calling the function...

Comment: (Unrelated, but why are you passing `this` if you're not using it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the `this` current element, as you are already passing the current element to the function, receive it and use it like

```js
function addToBasket(elem) {
  var bkval = $(elem).val();
  console.log(bkval);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="ferrari" id="F40" onclick="addToBasket(this);">F40
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get value of `this` which is element that you use `onclick`

```js
function addToBasket(e) {
  var bkval = e.value;
  console.log(bkval);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="ferrari" id="F40" onclick="addToBasket(this);">F40
```